# woocommerce language pack version higher than the woocommerce installation

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

would like to ask: Is it possible to use woocommerce language pack with version higher than the woocommerce installation itself? Assuming the higher version of the language pack is better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there will be no problem to do this if your WooCommerce is greater than 2.2+ version. Do a backup before that just to be sure.

Comment: Sorry for having been able to respond to your answer only now, Kasmetski. Noted, thanks for your info.